# Uniform convergence on an interval

Tags: proof-writing, uniform-convergence

Let $a<c<b$. Let {$f_n$} be a sequence of functions converging uniformly on $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$. Prove that {$f_n$} converges uniformly on $[a,b]$

My attempt:

Intuitively, I see that {$f_n$}  converges to a limit function {$f_1$} on $[a,c]$ and {$f_2$} on $[c,b]$.

Now, since the point $c$ is included in both cases, can I conclude that {$f_1$}={$f_2$}?

How to formally write the proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll take a shot at this

Here I'm letting $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined as
$$
   f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       f_a(x) & : x \in [a,c)\\
       f_b(x) & : x \in [c,b]
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$
 where I replace $f_1$ with $f_a$ and $f_2$ with $f_b$ from your answer (I did this because $f_1$ and $f_2$ are actually functions within the sequence)

Since we have $f_{n}\rightarrow f_a$ and $f_n\rightarrow f_b$ uniformly on $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$ respectively, this means that we have that for $\epsilon>0$ there exist an $N_1,N_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N_1$, then
$$|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$
for $x\in[a,c)$. Similarly we have for $n\geq N_2$, then
$$|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$
for $x\in[c,b]$.

Thus letting $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$, we have that for $n\geq N$, then
$$|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$
for $x\in[a,b]$
thus $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$

Comment: How is this $f(x)$ defined in $[a,b]$?

Comment: It is defined on $[a,b]$ it is just a piecewise function. Notice also that $f_a(c)=f_b(c)$ since cant have two different limits

Comment: I edited my answer hopefully that clarifies your question